# Como esconder api key do lado do cliente?

Tags: youtube-api

Ola, estou trabalhando com a api do youtube e no momento que o cliente faz as requisições preciso colocar na url uma key publica do desenvolvedor (no caso sou eu), ex:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=MINHA_KEY
```

Existe algum problema em deixar essa chave exposta? Se houver existe alguma maneira de esconde-la?

Obs: Estou usando requisições AJAX e o resultado é um json com os dados buscados!

Comment: Na configuração desta chave você não define quais os domínios permitidos a utilizá-la?

Comment: Configuro sim. Na verdade queria saber se existe algum risco em deixa-la exposta!!!

Comment: Então acredito que não tenha, visto que a mesma só funcionará no seu próprio site.

Comment: Ah sim...vlw!!!!